# How do I change host name

Tags: hostname

Getting 'unable to resolve host' error and need to change name. How do I do this?

Hostname is `brian-HP-G60-Notebook-PC`

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   linux

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Think my hostname is way to difficult to remember :-)

No need for security on this machine.

Beginner in Linux so explicit help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

Set the name to what you'd like to use

My hostname file.

[image]

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

My hosts file. (ignore the sub domains, they are not needed for you, this is my development machine)

[image]

127.0.1.1

There is likely other stuff in the hosts file, like *127.0.0.1 localhost* Just leave the rest alone.

```
sudo hostname
```

should not error out.